# Magento 1.8 order product quantity per 0.1 decimals

Tags: php, magento

I'm using Magento 1.8 and I am amazed that I cannot get the system to allow orders of 0.1 quantity. I'm building this stor to sell fabrics, per 10cm's. So that would be 0.1meters and I do not want the quantity to represent centimeters.

I've tried the qty_increment field in the Admin > System > Configuration > Inventory  but it only accepts full integers. :-(

Anybody know how to solve this or is Magento simply not meant for this ?

Comment: !!! I actually found the solution, you CAN do this in the Backend by going to Product > Manage products > Select a product > Inventory > Enable Inventory > Enable Quantity uses Decimals > Stepsize 0.1 !!! SIDENOTE: Product price MUST be over 1 euro/dollar/any currency, or it won't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I actually found the solution, you CAN do this in the Backend by going to Product > Manage products > Select a product > Inventory > Enable Inventory > Enable Quantity uses Decimals > Stepsize 0.1 !!! SIDENOTE: Product price MUST be over 1 euro/dollar/any currency, or it won't work.

Comment: Cool! Don't forget to also set the Minimum Qty in Shopping Cart to 0.1 :-)

Answer (score 1):

You cant solve this out by changing the product type to configurable. Kindly follow these steps to resolve this,

- Create an attribute "weight"(name as you wish) by
  (`Admin->Catalog->Attributes->Manage Attributes`).
- Create a configurable attribute set "Configurable_Attribute_Set"(name
  as you wish) by (`Admin->Catalog->Attributes->Manage Attributes
  Sets`).
- Assign the custom attribute(weight) to our new attribute
  set(Configurable_Attribute_Set).
- Create new product with new configurable type/assign this new set to
  existing product.
- Now, set the Inventory area default and set the quantity in the
  weight attribute(This allows you to enter decimal values).

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi V_J_S, I also found this option when Google-ing my prolblem, but this would mean that per product, I would have to introduce a list from 0.1 up to 20.0 in steps of 0.1 ... not very attractive.

Comment: I can understand your problem. You can achieve the same using the steps which I updated. Please have a try and let me know where you struggled. Thanks

Comment: Hi V_J_S , thanks for your quick adjustements :) I tried this, but this will mean customers will have to order Amount:1 of Weight:0.7 for example. This is not the way the shop owner likes to go. I'm further looking at the possiblities and maybe SQL insertion even to enable decimal qty now.

Comment: !!! I actually found the solution, you CAN do this in the Backend by going to Product > Manage products > Select a product > Inventory > Enable Inventory > Enable Quantity uses Decimals > Stepsize 0.1 !!! SIDENOTE: Product price MUST be over 1 euro/dollar/any currency, or it won't work.

Comment: super. Let me update this in my mind for future reference. Thanks.